# React Native metro server fails, bundling error

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler

[The Error screen on the Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otEZx.png)

While working on an app, suddenly i faced this error

```
 bundling failed: Error: While resolving module `react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen`, the Haste package `react-native` was found. However the module `Libraries/NewAppScreen` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\NewAppScreen(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\NewAppScreen\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
    at resolveHasteName (C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:236:9)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:103:20)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:143:31)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
    at C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:399:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:18)
    at C:\Users\hp\practice\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:269:33
```

I am new to this framework and just started. So i am not what this error means.So if anybody can help in explaining and finding the solution , it woulfd be a great help.